# Exporting Ruby CSV from ActiveRecord single quote in Excel looks weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv

When I open the exported CSV file from Excel after extracting data from my table using the [Ruby's CSV library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). I open the file using Excel (all of my users use Excel to open my CSV files). It comes out funky looking. Here's some screen shots.

I tried converting converting it to ASCII, but I get an error:
`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+2019 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII`

```
CSV.open(fileNameInbound, 'wb', :encoding => Encoding::US_ASCII) do |csv| 
  myModel.all.each do |m| 
    csv << m 
  end 
end
```

My users are not tech savvy so I cannot have them trying to change it to UTF-8 or something.

In Sublime Text looks like this:

[image]

In Excel looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your csv file is utf-8 encoded. Try opening it in utf-8 mode in Excel (if that's possible), or write the file as ascii if it doesn't contain special characters.

Comment: I tried doing:
`CSV.open(fileNameInbound, 'wb', :encoding => Encoding::US_ASCII) do |csv|`

I get this error:
`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+2019 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII`

Comment: Yes, because your file is in utf-8 encoding. You could try to write it in ascii encoding or open it as utf-8 in Excel.

Comment: I showed the beginning of the code. I am writing it from the table to CSV and adding the encoding ASCII 
`CSV.open(fileNameInbound, 'wb', :encoding => Encoding::US_ASCII) do |csv|
 myModel.all.each do |m|
    csv << m
  end
end`

Comment: If the data is pure US-ASCII then you should be able to write the file in UTF-8 or US-ASCII as the first 128 characters in UTF-8 correspond to US-ASCII.

So since this does not show up properly: the single quote is probably not in US-ASCII but something else?

Comment: I think is the fancy back quote that throws Excel off. The simple ' works.

Comment: I fixed my issue. Thanks Danny_ds. I answered is below.

Comment: I don't get why the downvote? It's so dumb how some people have genuine issues and try their best to ask them and some random person could down vote it and making the question obscure. This is super helpful and I am sure many people are struggling sharing data and not displaying correctly in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding BOM characters in the beginning of my file to force the UTF-8 in Excel.

```
CSV.open(fileNameInbound, 'wb', encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv| 
  myModel.all.each do |m| 
    csv << ['\xef\xbb\xbf']
    csv << m 
  end 
end
```